# How to use the ID of an item after loading combobox from database.?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=RSTT2; database = Project ;  User Id=sa; Password=PeaTeaCee5#");
    con.Open();
    string strCmd = "select ID,Name from Employee";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cbSupportID.DataSource = ds;
    cbSupportID.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cbSupportID.ValueMember = "ID";
    cbSupportID.Enabled = true;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

now i want use the id of items in my form to process..Plzz tell me the best solution with code.

Comment: What is happening with this code? I don't see anything immediately incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now you simply retrieve your selected combobox `ID` value using

```
cbSupportID.SelectedValue
```

eg.

```
If cbSupportID.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
    textBox1.Text = cbSupportID.SelectedValue.ToString()
End If
```

You can also access other useful properties like `SelectedIndex` (starting from 0...) or `SelectedItem`.

check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2